# Need to resolve the group by error (ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Here is my query:

```
  select 
    A.school_dim_id,
    A.platform_dim_id,
    A.month_dim_id,
    CASE WHEN B.SCHOOLTYPE NOT IN ('International') THEN B.ROLLSIZE
    WHEN B.SCHOOLTYPE IN ('International') THEN MAX(D.ROLE_SIZE)
    END ROLL_SIZE
  from  
      rag_raw_event_detail_fact A inner join rag_school_dim B on (A.school_dim_id = B.school_dim_id)
      inner join rag_subscription_detail_fact C on (A.school_dim_id = C.school_dim_id)
      inner join rag_intl_school_roll_static D on (D.isbn = c.isbn)
      inner join rag_platform_dim E on (E.platform_dim_id = A.platform_dim_id)
  where 
      E.PLATFORM_EVENT = 'alp_wordsmith_resources_opened'
      and C.service in ('PriHubsWordsmith','PriHubsWordsmithGlobal')
      and C.enddate > sysdate
  group by
      A.school_dim_id,
      A.platform_dim_id,
      A.month_dim_id
```

While running the above SQL, I'm getting the error as mentioned below:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 5 Column: 13

I need help to overcome the above error.

Comment: You have columns names `ROLLSIZE` and `ROLL_SIZE` in your data?  You are mixing aggregation functions and non-aggregation in the same `case`.  I think you should provide sample data and desired results.  You query has problems.

Comment: Hi Gordon, 
 i have rag_school_dim.ROLLSIZE and rag_intl_school_roll_static.ROLE_SIZE as column name in two different tables.

if the rag_school_dim.schooltype is not 'International' have to take the rollsize from school_dim table, else max(role_size) from rag_intl_school_roll_static

Answer (score 0):

You must place all columns from SELECT which is not in group function in GROUP BY section. So it will be:

```
select 
    A.school_dim_id,
    A.platform_dim_id,
    A.month_dim_id,
    CASE WHEN B.SCHOOLTYPE NOT IN ('International') THEN B.ROLLSIZE
    WHEN B.SCHOOLTYPE IN ('International') THEN MAX(D.ROLE_SIZE)
    END ROLL_SIZE
  from  
      rag_raw_event_detail_fact A inner join rag_school_dim B on (A.school_dim_id = B.school_dim_id)
      inner join rag_subscription_detail_fact C on (A.school_dim_id = C.school_dim_id)
      inner join rag_intl_school_roll_static D on (D.isbn = c.isbn)
      inner join rag_platform_dim E on (E.platform_dim_id = A.platform_dim_id)
  where 
      E.PLATFORM_EVENT = 'alp_wordsmith_resources_opened'
      and C.service in ('PriHubsWordsmith','PriHubsWordsmithGlobal')
      and C.enddate > sysdate
  group by
      A.school_dim_id,
      A.platform_dim_id,
      A.month_dim_id,
      B.SCHOOLTYPE,
      B.ROLLSIZE
```

But after that you may get not expected result. In that case you will have to rewrite your query.

Comment: Thanks much, its working now.

Comment: you can mark answer as correct if it solves your problem ;)